# What is a Monad in the two category $\mathsf{Rel}$?

Tags: category-theory, relations, higher-category-theory, monads, 2-categories

The 2-category $\mathsf{Rel}$ is a category with sets as $0$-cells, relations as $1$-cells (with relation composition as composition), and inclusions as $2$-cells (with vertical composition being the fact that inclusion is a preorder, and horizontal composition being the fact that relation composition respects inclusions.)

What is a monad in this category?

Answer (score 6):

A monad in $REL$ is a [preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder) on a set. To see this, note that we need a $1$-cell $R: A \to A$, a relation, such that we have $2$-cells:

$$\eta: id_A \to R$$
$$\mu: R \circ R \to R$$

but these are just inclusions $id_A \subseteq R$ and $R \circ R \subseteq R$.

$id_A \subseteq R$ means that if $x=y$ then $x R y$.

$R \circ R \subseteq R$ means that if $\exists y. xRy \wedge yRz$ then $xRz$.

These two conditions are the axioms of a preorder.

Comment: Similarly, a monad in the bicategory of spans is a category.

Comment: Of course, that only says what happens on the level of objects. The next question one should ask is, what is a morphism of monads?

Comment: @ZhenLin I was going to ask that, but then I would only have a partial answer.

Comment: @ZhenLin I am pretty sure it would just be inclusion of equivalence relations.

Comment: Inclusion of equivalence relations? We're talking about preorders! Anyway, part of the story here is that the morphisms of monads are _more general_ than order-preserving maps. In order to get these morphisms, you need to use the [proarrow equipment](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-category+equipped+with+proarrows) structure which axiomatizes the interplay between relations and functions, or spans and functions, or profunctors and functors, or bimodules and ring homomorphisms, or...

Comment: @tcamps Whoops I meant preorders